# Failover switch Walk through

Tags: backup, internet, hardware

Our internet goes out frequently and I would like to failover to either dial up or cellular connection but only for a matter of minutes.  Apparantly I am right out of the range for internet and have tried using a signal booster/repeater.

Is there a hardware/software set up that can be walked through easily?  Yes I would like a walk through of the software with step by step directions.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to the original question (that was asking for something "dead easy"): no there isn't.

Long answer:

You could find something good enough for you if you were willing to give up on one of the features:

1. dead easy
2. pure software solution

If you accept something that's definitely not dead easy, but that gives you much power in return, then I'm sure you've already found several possible solutions, one of which could be configuring Linux as a router with failover.

On the other hand, if you want it somewhat easier than becoming a network administrator (but "easier" is quite subjective anyway), and you can accept a new piece of hardware, then there are several routers out there that can fall back automatically to a mobile connection when the main upstream connection fails. They implement that in software after all, but you need the damn router to run that software.

EDIT after the OP edited the question, changing "dead easy" into "that can be walked through easily":

Keep in mind that "easily" is still very subjective and that the problem itself is all but easy. That said, I'd recommend the ASUS DSL-AC88U (a.k.a. AC3100) router. It runs AsusWRT system software which I find very intuitive and well designed.

Comment: I feel like this should be a comment

Comment: No, this is an answer. The short version is the exact answer to your question, because even hardware/software solutions to a complex problem will never be dead easy to configure. The long version may be a comment, but it tries to explain why the plain simple answer is "no".

Comment: Okay please provide a recommendation then.

Comment: I can't recommend anything that satisfies your question, since it does not exist.